# Error: The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datetime, gridview

I know that there are simmilar questions like this on the forum, however I am still having problems to update a datetime field o the database. I dont get any problems when inserting but I get problems when updating and I am formating the same way , like this:

> e.Values.Item("SelectionStartDate") = Format(startdate, "yyyy-MM-dd")
>   + " " + startTime1 + ".000"

startTime is of type string.

I have tried different solution that I came across on the internet but still get this error.
Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show what the right-hand side actually evaluates to? We can't tell you what's wrong with the output string if we can't see the output string.

Comment: can the datatype be varchar instead of nvarchar?

Comment: @satish while I agree varchar would be more appropriate, that wouldn't change whether it would work or not.

Comment: For the real ISO-8601 format which works on all instances of SQL Server, you need to separate the date from the time portion with a **`T`** like this: `2012-04-02T08:44:123.000` - not a space as you have it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using DateTime.TryParse with appropriate [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Comment: thanks you for the answer, however if I do  e.NewValues.Item("SelectionStartDate") = Date.ParseExact(e.NewValues.Item("SelectionStartDate"), "YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) I get this error ex = {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}

Comment: if you do - you still get exception?

Comment: Monthes are marked as two upper case "MM", maybe this is a problem? What is your "startdate" value? Try to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

if the insert work, I think the problem is on your calculation (the + " " + startTime1 + ".000")

try removing it (update the date to the same date) just for testing. If it works I suggest formatting the date on startdate and pass it. you can use @Johnny_D's method.

EDIT:

```
System.TimeSpan addDate = new System.TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0); //add one day
System.DateTime new_date = startdate.Add(addDate);
e.Values.Item("SelectionStartDate") = new_date;
```

Comment: I tried to do this way to check if I still get the error        e.NewValues.Item("SelectionStartDate") = "2009-04-01 00:00:00.000" but I still get the same error.

Comment: try something simpler like datetime.now()

Comment: Works fine with datetime.now ... I dont know whats the problem

Comment: I just removed dateTime.now and added   e.NewValues.Item("SelectionStartDate") = Format(startdate, "yyyy-MM-dd") + " " + startTime1 + ".000" and is working now, I havent changed single line of the code and is working now!!